# Can the academic editor accept a paper if the reviewers have opposite opinions?

Tags: peer-review

I have submitted a paper for review. I have made 4 revisions. The one reviewer accepted the paper and the other reviewer rejected the paper. Is there any chance that my paper will be totally accepted by the editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referees do not accept or reject articles. They make a suggestion to the editor to accept or reject the submission. Depending on the journal, it is either the handling editor themselves, or the handling editor in discussion with the rest of the editorial board, who actually makes the decision.

If the journal has very high standards, it may be quite unusual to accept a paper if any referee recommends against it. In other cases, it will be a matter of how exactly the referees justify their recommendations, how much the editor trusts each of them, what the editors impression of the paper is, and so on.